# Keeping a collection of mercuial subrepos at tip

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, mercurial-subrepos, subrepos

I would like to keep a collection of mercurial subprepositories updates at `tip` and this is what I've come up with. Are there any gotchas I'm not seeing if I do it this way?

#### Backstory

For many years now I have been using monolithic subversion repository `main` but I am getting ready to convert it over to mercurial. The only thing I don't like about mercurial is that I can't clone just one subdirectory. I was thinking of making each top level directory of `main` into its own mercurial repository. Then I could create one mercurial repo called `maincollections` that would reference each new mercurial repo as a subrepo. In order to get changes to any subrepo by just pulling once inside `maincollections` I set up the following.

#### Method

When a push is received on the server in any one of the subrepos it triggers the `changegroup` hook `commit-sub` to force an update and commit of `.hgsubstate` in the `maincollections` repo.

commit-subs

```
#!/bin/bash
SUBNAME=$(basename $(pwd))
cd ../../maincollection/$SUBNAME
hg pull
hg up
cd ..
hg ci -m "Automated update of .hgsubstate"
```

Directory organization

```
maincollection # repo with subrepos
main/*         # Individual subrepos
```

Comment: There is actually support for narrow clones using an extension from google: https://bitbucket.org/Google/narrowhg

Comment: Hm, thanks. Downside is it only works with the most recent version(s) of mercurial (that information is buried as a comment in an open issue). I'll have to get a backport to try it because Ubuntu 16.04 is shipping with v3.7

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use debian packages from ubuntu? It's almost trivial to build mercurial from source and mercurial's makefile has a "make deb" target.

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't know it had a `make deb`. Strictly speaking I don't need to use a package, but I haven't updated my methods to handle custom PYTHONPATHs

Comment: PPA with Mercurial 4.4 -> https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/releases